# Correctly annotate a numba function using jit

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I started with this code to calculate a simple matrix multiplication. It runs with %timeit in around 7.85s on my machine.

To try to speed this up I tried cython which reduced the time to 0.4s. I want to also try to use numba jit compiler to see if I can get similar speed ups (with less effort). But adding the @jit annotation appears to give exactly the same timings (~7.8s). I know it can't figure out the types of the calculate_z_numpy() call but I'm not sure what I can do to coerce it. Any ideas?

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit('f8(c8[:],c8[:],uint)')
def calculate_z_numpy(q, z, maxiter):
    """use vector operations to update all zs and qs to create new output array"""
    output = np.resize(np.array(0, dtype=np.int32), q.shape)
    for iteration in range(maxiter):
        z = z*z + q
        done = np.greater(abs(z), 2.0)
        q = np.where(done, 0+0j, q)
        z = np.where(done, 0+0j, z)
        output = np.where(done, iteration, output)
    return output

def calc_test():
    w = h = 1000
    maxiter = 1000
    # make a list of x and y values which will represent q
    # xx and yy are the co-ordinates, for the default configuration they'll look like:
    # if we have a 1000x1000 plot
    # xx = [-2.13, -2.1242,-2.1184000000000003, ..., 0.7526000000000064, 0.7584000000000064, 0.7642000000000064]
    # yy = [1.3, 1.2948, 1.2895999999999999, ..., -1.2844000000000058, -1.2896000000000059, -1.294800000000006]
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = -2.13, 0.77, -1.3, 1.3

    x_step = (float(x2 - x1) / float(w)) * 2
    y_step = (float(y1 - y2) / float(h)) * 2
    y = np.arange(y2,y1-y_step,y_step,dtype=np.complex)
    x = np.arange(x1,x2,x_step)
    q1 = np.empty(y.shape[0],dtype=np.complex)
    q1.real = x
    q1.imag = y
    # Transpose y
    x_y_square_matrix = x+y[:, np.newaxis] # it is np.complex128
    # convert square matrix to a flatted vector using ravel
    q2 = np.ravel(x_y_square_matrix)
    # create z as a 0+0j array of the same length as q
    # note that it defaults to reals (float64) unless told otherwise
    z = np.zeros(q2.shape, np.complex128)
    output = calculate_z_numpy(q2, z, maxiter)
    print(output)

calc_test()
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to do this with some help from someone else.

```
@jit('i4[:](c16[:],c16[:],i4,i4[:])',nopython=True)
def calculate_z_numpy(q, z, maxiter,output):
    """use vector operations to update all zs and qs to create new output array"""
    for iteration in range(maxiter):
        for i in range(len(z)):
            z[i] = z[i] + q[i]
            if z[i] > 2:
                output[i] = iteration
                z[i] = 0+0j
                q[i] = 0+0j
    return output
```

What I learnt is that use numpy datastructures as inputs (for typing), but within use c like paradigms for looping.

This runs in 402ms which is a touch faster than cython code 0.45s so for fairly minimal work in rewriting the loop explicitly we have a python version faster than C(just).